# Modeling a many-to-many relationship

Tags: database, postgresql

I have two tables, table `Project` and `User`. Below is the relationship between these two tables

> A Project can be associated with multiple users
>   A User can operate on multiple projects

I have created below entity relationship. Is this the correct way to represent a many to many relationship?

```
User:
    id
    name
    email

Project:
    id
    name

User_Project: 
    user_id
    project_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, provided you have foreign key relationships `(user_id) REFERENCES "user"(id)` and `(project_id) REFERENCES project(id)` defined and a `PRIMARY KEY (user_id, project_id)`.

BTW, try to avoid mixed case names and reserved keywords in table and column names.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct.

Because users can join multiple projects it is necessary to add a junction table.

[image]

Junction tables can also contain additional columns.

In your case it might be useful to know when a user joined a project. 
So you could add a column *join_date* where you store that information.

```
create table users
(
  id            serial,
  name          text,
  email         text,

  primary key (id) 
);

create table projects
(
  id            serial,
  name          text,

  primary key (id)    
);

create table users_projects
(
  user_id       int,
  project_id    int,
  join_date     date,

  primary key (user_id, project_id),
  foreign key (user_id) references users (id),
  foreign key (project_id) references projects (id)
);
```